# AC clutch doesn't get engaged

Tags: ac, troubleshooting, repair, buick, air-compressor

My 2007 Buick lacrosse was giving warm air when I turn on AC and I looked compressor and clutch wasn't turning so I thought I am low on refrigerant and went the shop did recharge and it was working just fine till I turned on the heater and turned off(to test) then turned on AC and the same problem again. What might be the problem?

I didn't use this car for 4-5 months and never turned on AC for like the last 6-7 months

Comment: Sounds like there could be a leak or seals have dried out - due to lack of use. get it checked - find out if it has lost fluid etc

Comment: This happened right after they recharged the ac. After the shop I was going to work and wanted to test by turning the heater on and off then ac stopped working

Comment: I did ac bypass but when I remove the clip ac stops working again. What can I do?

Comment: Did you happen to hear a hissing noise inside the car while AC was still working?

Comment: No hissing or any other noises. AC was ice cold but when I remove the paper clip AC would stop. Maybe not turning on AC for a long time caused a problem.

Comment: @Sami Sounds like a faulty pressure sensor/pressure switch to me.

Comment: That makes sense since the air compressor is working and giving cold air. Thank you again!! I don't think it will cost a lot to replace.

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem has solved. It was the low ac pressure switch, not high-pressure switch.